# How to call a https firebase function in scheduled firebase function to keep it warm and avoid cold start

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

One of the ways to avoid firebase function cold start is to keep it warm all the time, for example invoke the function every 1 min.

Recently firebase added scheduled functions as below

```
export scheduledFunction = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 5 minutes').onRun((context) => {
  console.log('This will be run every 5 minutes!');
  // call another function on same project
});
```

My question is how can I call another https firebase functions on same project to keep that function warm? (for sure without hard coding the domain name)

Comment: There is no guarantee that you can keep a function "warm".  New server instances may be allocated or deallocated at any time, depending on current load and other factors.  When a new instance is allocated, it will experience a cold start.

Comment: @DougStevenson thanks, I know, I try to minimum the issue we are facing

Comment: @DougStevenson however how can I call another function inside of the schedule function

Comment: You can't directly invoke another background function. You have to make a change that would trigger it.

Comment: @DougStevenson I meant another https function

Comment: @DougStevenson also `params` in the context is empty object, how can I pass soemthing
`{"eventId":"599727663713388","timestamp":"2019-06-28T20:36:00.075Z","eventType":"google.pubsub.topic.publish","resource":{"service":"pubsub.googleapis.com","name":"projects/myproj/topics/firebase-schedule-scheduledFunction-us-central1","type":"type.googleapis.com/google.pubsub.v1.PubsubMessage"},"params":{}}`

Comment: Just invoke the functions url any way you want.